# Issue with performing a $save on a new resource in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am attempting to implement a sample application with Angular that interacts with a backend REST API using $resource objects.  However, the backend system does not generate id's for the resources, so these need to be defined on the objects being created on the client.  This causes a problem when invoking the $save method on the new'ed resource because it forces the JSON data to be POSTed to the wrong URL, i.e., it POSTs to:

```
/resources/employees/1234
```

rather than:

```
/resources/employees
```

I would prefer not to have to drop down to using the low level $http service if I can avoid it.

Does anyone know how I can work around this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the fact that you configured your `$resource` constructor in this way, for example:

```
$resource('resources/employees/:employeeId', {
    employeeId: @id
});
```

That means that when you call methods like `$save` or `$delete` etc. on the resource objects made by this constructor, the variable `:employeeId` in the url will be filled with the value `id` that exist on the object on which you called the method. To avoid this you have to modify the constructor config so that the url variable does not depend on the object `id` property.